# Java application requires Admin Access to run when placed in Program Files

Tags: java, javafx, launch4j

I am working on a Java (JavaFX) desktop app. I am converting it to exe with **launch4j** tool and then later creating a setup package using **Inno Setup Compiler** (default installation path set to C:\Program Files (x86))
The application itself don't need any admin privileges and runs fine when I copy the exe on desktop or run it on drives other than C. (Also works fine if I run it in local appdata folder)
But I need to place it in Program Files (x86) directory.
The app doesn't open if I install it in that directory so I had to create a manifest file for launch4j so that it asks admin access each time it opens. It works fine that way but admin access is asked everytime in this case.

I need to make this application run without asking admin access each time.
If there is any solution, please guide me through it.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is your program doing? Is it trying to read/write files anywhere?

Comment: @user31601 Yes. It's reading a file from %APPDATA% directory which is actually appdata/roaming directory.

Comment: Thanks @user31601. I changes the location for application data to local jar's path and now it's working in "Program Files (x86)" folder as well.
You can post your solution as answer and I'll approve it :)

Comment: That's OK - I was more just 'asking around the problem'. I wouldn't say I proposed a full solution. Glad you fixed it though! If you want, write the solution yourself, just for other people's reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I kind of figured that out. I guess the jar was having trouble reading from system directories and I had to do some read/write operations on a config file. So I changed the config path to:

```
String path = Controller.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath() + "\\Data\\";
```

Now it creates a folder named "Data" inside jar file and read/write from there. I don't know if this is a bad practice or not but it seems to work pretty good for me.

Thanks a lot to @user31601 who gave me some hint that helped me figure this solution out.